# peer effects and forbidden regressions

Tags: regression, instrumental-variables

im reading a stats-book ([ftp://nozdr.ru/biblio/kolxo3/G/GL/Angrist%20J.D.,%20Pischke%20J.-S.%20Mostly%20Harmless%20Econometrics%20(PUP,%202008)(ISBN%20069112034X)(O)(290s)*GL*.pdf](ftp://nozdr.ru/biblio/kolxo3/G/GL/Angrist%20J.D.,%20Pischke%20J.-S.%20Mostly%20Harmless%20Econometrics%20(PUP,%202008)(ISBN%20069112034X)(O)(290s)_GL_.pdf)), where on page 146 they tackle the question if peer effects can be investigated by regressing individual properties (high school graduation) on higher order properties (high school graduation rate). They argue that this is mistaken, since a regression of  $s_{ij}$ on $\bar{S}_j$ would always have a coefficient of one. As proof, they start with a formula which I dont understand:
$
\frac{\sum_{\substack{j}} \sum_{\substack{i}} s_{ij}(\bar{S}_j - \bar{S})}{\sum_{\substack{j}} n_{j}(\bar{S}_j - \bar{S})^2} 
$
What is this? It looks like a Covariance over variance formula of a regression coefficient, but I dont recognize it. Where is $-\bar{s}_{ij}$ in the numerator? why is there a $n_j$ in the denominator? Probably, this is a standard formula I dont know because I not have a formal statistics training. I would be grateful for help.

Comment: This looks like a formula for the coefficient of $s_{ij}$ regressed on $\bar S_j$ (with ordinary least squares), exactly as described.  You can find many versions of this formula on our site or in regression textbooks.

Answer (score 1):

Fact about covariance:

$$E[(X-E(X)(Y-E(Y))] = E[X(Y-E(Y)]$$

Carry out the multiplications on both sides to verify. In words, we do not need to centered both rv's, it suffices to center the one, and we will get the exact same final result. The same holds for the sample analogues.

Regarding the "$n_j$" in the denominator: It represents the number of students in school $j$. Denote also $J$ the number of schools. You have two-dimensional data, but $\bar S_j$ is invariant over $n_j$.  If you pool the data (and the numerator suggests so), in the total sample of $\sum_j^J n_j $ data points the variable $\bar S_j$ appears $n_j$ times. Take it from here.